# Method with Out and Without Out

Tags: c#, .net, methods, out

I am working on a refactoring pretty old code.
I have two method which implement the exact same logic.
The only difference is - one is with Out parameter and other without it.
I know why we use out but is there any way I can combine this two into single one.

```
 public bool Read(string column1, string column2)
    {
        const int FIRST_COLUMN = 0;
        const int SECOND_COLUMN = 1;

        string line;
        string[] columns;

        char[] separator = { '\t' };

        line = ReadLine();
        columns = line.Split(separator);

        if (columns.Length == 0)
        {
            column1 = null;
            column2 = null;

            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            column1 = columns[FIRST_COLUMN];
            column2 = columns[SECOND_COLUMN];

            return true;
        }
    }

    public bool Read(out string column1, out string column2)
    {
        const int FIRST_COLUMN = 0;
        const int SECOND_COLUMN = 1;

        string line;
        string[] columns;

        char[] separator = { '\t' };

        line = ReadLine();

        if (line == null)
        {
            column1 = null;
            column2 = null;

            return false;
        }

        columns = line.Split(separator);

        if (columns.Length == 0)
        {
            column1 = null;
            column2 = null;

            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            column1 = columns[FIRST_COLUMN];
            column2 = columns[SECOND_COLUMN];

            return true;
        }
    }
```

Is there any way I can write it into one method?

Comment: If `s1` and `s2` are modified in the first one the caller won't see those changes so I doubt they do the same thing.

Comment: Looking at the signatures, these two methods should be doing different things, or there is a design issue here (the out parameter specifier is redundant) and one of them can be got rid of. Please provide method bodies

Comment: Will need to see the method bodies to see if they can be merged, or atleast how they interact with `s1` and `s2`.

Comment: Adding the method body as well

Comment: The only reasonable method is the second one. The method without `out` arguments doesn't make sense.

Comment: Why does the first method take `column1` and `column2` at all? It never uses them.

Comment: They do the same thing in that they both return a bool and strings are passed either byref/out. In terms of readability use the second one, but ease of use (no out keyword required) use the first. I'd keep what ever else is in the code base, looks like you're using a bool pattern to detect success, but observe how the .Net framework do it with OBJECT SENDER, EVENTARHS E. Honestly move on, there's bigger issues to handle.

Comment: Well Visual studio will give warnings about unnecessary assignments for the first method.

Comment: @jerermythompson they most definitely don’t do the same, where did you get that idea?

Comment: So to answer your question "Is there any way I can write it into one method?", yes, remove the first one. If it is used to determine whether the line has a valid format, create a new method that doesn't take parameters, returns a boolean and calls the 2nd one with dummy out parameters.

Comment: Combine it into a method that does not use the 'out' keywords in the parameters, but then instead return back a new object that contains the new values for column1, column2 and the column.Length == 0.